# How do Superman and Lois Lane leave the North Pole?

Tags: dc, superman, superman-2

In Superman 2, how do Superman and Lois Lane make it back from the North Pole after Superman removes his powers in that 'power removal machine'?

[image]

A few minutes after this scene, Clark and Lois are in a truck stop with American staff and American customers, so I'm assuming they've made it back to America.

If Clark can no longer fly, how did they leave the North Pole?
They have no protective clothing or supplies so surely they couldn't have just walked could they?

Comment: [Boom Tube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boom_tube)?!?

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza That would be awesome. In the directors cut perhaps?? :)

Comment: Actually, it's canada not America : **Scene : 279** EXT CANADA - ROAD - NIGHT : *A rented car speeds quickly down a northern Canadian highway*; http://www.supermanhomepage.com/movies/superman_II_shoot.txt

Comment: They went next door to Santa's Workshop and bummed a ride on the flying sleigh.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Superman and Lois used the telephone to call the Arctic police and bum a lift back to civilisation.**

**No. Seriously.**

As you can see from this deleted scene, in the Superman 2 universe, the police have a regular presence in the Arctic and Clark evidently has a way to contact them (from the Fortress of Solitude) in order to allow them to arrest Lex and the three supervillains.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think there's any reason to assume the Fortress is at the North Pole. As well as the issue you state, we later see Clark hitch-hiking back there, which again would be impossible if it actually was at the Pole.

All we know from the film is that it is somewhere remote and snowy. But that's just as likely to be remote Canada or Alaska.

Comment: From the original script : **At the North Pole, young Clark throws the Green Crystal and where it falls the Fortress of Solitude begins to rise.**

Comment: Luthor indicates that the Fortress is in the North Pole shortly after Superman defeats Zod, Non and Ursa near the end of the film: _"Look... look, Superman... I got a proposition for you. Now don't stop me till you've heard this, because... well, I know I owe you one, but... **we're in the North Pole, right?** Let's wipe the slate clean. If you give me a ride back, I promise to turn over a whole new leaf..."_

Answer (score -3):

There really is no good answer, besides just writer/director oversight. The Fortress of Solitude is in the North Pole!! That fact is undisputed. So, since there were clearly no roads, and they had no warm clothes. Lois was in a dress & heels, and Clark was in a button down shirt, and slacks!! There's just no plausible way they could have returned to civilization on foot.