# Is Superman a murderer in Superman II?

Tags: dc, superman, superman-2

I recently watched the extended version of [Superman II](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081573/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).  I hadn’t watched it since I was a child, so I didn’t really remember it in detail.  After watching it, I was genuinely surprised.

After depowering General Zod, Ursa, and Non, he seems to commit murder.  Zod posed no threat, as his powers were gone, but Superman throws him against a wall and lets him fall, presumably to his death.  Non leaps to attack Superman and falls in the same pit.  Lois punches Ursa, who also falls into the pit.

None of them posed a threat to Superman and he could have easily saved them and had them incarcerated.  This would be considered murder in a court of law.

So is Superman a murderer?

Yes, he does reverse time back to the beginning of the movie, in a deus ex machina moment.  However, to me, that doesn’t change his actions at the time.

Comment: Isn't the time reversing in the first movie, not the second? In Superman II the only "reset" is the magical kiss that makes Lois forget everything.

Comment: @DanielRoseman this was the extended Richard Donner cut. There were scenes not in the theatrical release.

Comment: For those who down vote provide a reason. It's a legitimate question.

Comment: @user23298 I'm guessing the reason for the downvotes is that you're essentially inviting an ethics discussion based entirely on personal opinion. Try to rephrase it in a way that would allow for a more objective answer.

Comment: If I was Superman's lawyer, I'd be arguing for a change of venue to Krypton.

Comment: Also, if I was Superman's lawyer, I'd be rubbing my greedy hands together with glee at the prospect of a 900 day trial, 899 days of which would be legal arguments.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield you forget the fact he threw a depowered Zod into the pit. Zod posed no threat.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield They all fell into a pit and then he collapsed the fortress of solitude on top of them.  In the arctic.  its safe to assume they are dead.

Comment: @user23298 - Zod was Ursa's commanding officer. She has her arm around Lois' throat. He clearly does represent an ongoing threat in the sense that he could order Ursa to kill Lois.

Comment: This is the strangest debate/question I've seen here.  It all spins on the wild assumption that the Zod & Co were thrown into some bottomless pit.  Why?  They slide into fog/mist and vanish.  I've always assumed they did a slippy-slide fall a few meters into a holding cell of some sort.  Let them cool off until Superman returned.  And years later when I saw the cut with the "Arctic Police", my assumption was confirmed.  Further to that, Superman had prepped his fortress for this encounter, so adding the holding cell was perfectly feasible.

Comment: Recently, Jack O’Halloran, who played Non, pointed out "Donner filmed an extra scene that confirmed all three villains survived and were carted off to a terrestrial prison instead of the Phantom Zone. “We shot an ending where they bring us out and put us in a police car and take us off to jail,” the actor and former heavyweight boxer says now, exonerating Superman of his supposed crime." see https://uk.movies.yahoo.com/superman-ii-christopher-reeve-jack-o-halloran-alternate-ending-140028071.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, and no, and yes, and no and yes.

### Yes

Superman [clearly](https://youtu.be/pEHiCrGjlTw?t=3m55s) disposes of Zod when he's de-powered. This would appear to be the very definition of [Excessive Force](http://definitions.uslegal.com/e/excessive-force/) given that he's not an immediate threat to Superman.

### No

Except that Zod does still arguably pose a substantial *[ongoing](https://www.justia.com/criminal/defenses/self-defense/)* threat to Superman and Lois. Firstly, he might order Ursa to kill Lois. Secondly, he will almost certainly seek to regain his superpowers and attack Superman again. Superman could easily argue that he still feared for Lois' life (as a clear and present threat) as well as his own life *in future*, justifying his use of lethal force in self-defence.

### Yes and No

Having said that, If Superman was in Massachusetts he'd probably be convicted of murder. Except that he's not, he's at the centre of the Arctic, itself a [hotly disputed legal grey zone](http://www.arcticcentre.org/EN/RESEARCH/NIEM/Projects/International-Arctic-Law), where normal laws don't apply

### Yes

Except that they do apply in the Richard Donner Cut where we see that the Arctic has its own [Police Force](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70909/how-do-superman-and-lois-lane-leave-the-north-pole/70910#70910), and presumably its own laws and judiciary.

### No

Except that neither Zod, nor Superman is human. Although you could argue that Superman is a US citizen, Zod certainly isn't and there are [no laws that specifically forbid the deliberate killing of non-terrestrials](http://www.xenology.info/Xeno/26.3.4.htm).

---

So there you go. Clear as mud.

Comment: I wonder what the rational was regarding the deleted police scene mentioned in Valorums post (see Yes #2). It almost seems as if the writers were prescient of the very discussion we are having here and were attempting the "justice" part of Supes...motto. Then perhaps during editing it was realized that it makes no sense. Has anyone seen anything from the writers/producers/etc explaining this scene?

Comment: @Withywindle - Asked (and [answered](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125062/is-clark-kent-a-legally-adopted-u-s-citizen/125084#125084)) elsewhere on SFF:SE

Comment: Re your final "No": They were aware of this problem as far back as [Lord Coke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_in_English_law#Actus_reus), who defines murder as killing "**any reasonable creature** in rerum natura under the King's peace". It's unclear to me whether that common law definition has been superseded by a statutory definition, but if not, expect a lot of complicated legal wrangling. If you want to use US law, you have the additional problem that there are at least 50 separate jurisdictions with independent definitions of murder (it's not a federal crime at all).

Comment: "Superman is a US citizen, Zod certainly isn't" - Is it legal for US citizens to kill non-citizens?

Comment: @colmde -  Please show me the relevant statue that says that a US citizen can't kill a space alien.

Comment: Lois, potentially murdering Ursa, wouldn't have the same legal rights

Comment: @jim - As above, please point me at the relevant statute that says that a human can't murder an alien, not even particularly in self-defence

Comment: Looking at the wiki definition of animals, this doesn't seem to preclude Zod et al from at least being defined as animals (I may be wrong but I didn't see anything that restricted the definition to something from Earth, but could be mistaken).  Recently animals have been recognised in UK law (but not international law) as sentient and have rights against being treated cruelly (https://www.companionlife.co.uk/animals-to-be-formally-recognised-as-sentient-beings-in-domestic-law/). In scifi, for example, Destiny of the Daleks, Davros was brought to stand trial for  crimes against sentient life.

Comment: @jim -  Believe it or not, in UK law it's very much easier. He's certainly not an animal (since by definition he's not a member of the "*[Sub-phylum Vertebrata of the Phylum Chordata](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/45/section/1)*") whereas a 'person' is defined as "*unquestionably living human beings **of the species Homo sapiens.***". Zod is neither, hence he would have no legal protection under UK law.

Comment: OK, fair point BUT in the superman science fiction world, given the introduction of aliens it is reasonable to assume that the laws would be changed

Answer (score 5):

There is no clearcut evidence in Superman II that anyone died at the end of the theatrical release of the film. although I admit it might be implied.

"but Superman throws him against a wall and lets him fall, presumably to his death. Non leaps to attack Superman and falls in the same pit. Lois punches Ursa, who also falls into the pit."

Yes, *PRESUMABLY* to their death(s).  But we did not see a pit full of corpses, all we saw was Superman's conversation with Lex Luthor and Lois Lane, then it cuts away to him flying her back to civilization.  Since it seems that it wasn't nearly as cold inside the fortress of solitude (no one was wearing winter coats or anything), one could also presume that Superman merely trapped them in the pit and came back later to take them to jail.

Furthermore, in other releases of the film and deleted scenes added to various viewings, the fate of the criminals is revealed.  In one version they are arrested, and in another version Superman turns back time which re-imprisoned them in the phantom zone.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman_II#Later_releases
In 1984, when Superman II premiered on television, 24 minutes were re-inserted into the film (17 minutes on ABC). Much of the extra footage was directed by Richard Donner. In the ABC-TV version, a U.S. "polar patrol" is shown picking up the three Kryptonians and Lex Luthor at the end of the film. Without this ending, it appears that Superman has let the Kryptonians die, though Superman has a strict code against killing and their deaths aren't necessary once they are depowered. On the other hand, the theatrical version's ending implies that Luthor is left stranded at the Fortress of Solitude, leaving the viewer to wonder how he got to prison in Superman IV: The Quest for Peace — that question was answered in the extended versions where Superman reverses the rotation of the Earth where one of the things he does involves preventing Lex Luthor from escaping from prison. The ending of the extended cuts also has Superman, with Lois standing beside him, destroying the Fortress of Solitude.

Comment: For the record, in none of the draft scripts does Zod die; *"ZOD is hurled helplessly through the air the entire length of the Fortress, crashes against the far wall, drops to the floor."*  - http://bigapricot.org/scripts/superman_II.txt

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment: If Superman did kill Zod et al, then I suspect (given some of the other arguments presented in the comments) that he could be indicted on these crimes.

In [Action Comics #358](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_358), “SUPERMAN…GUILTY OF HOMICIDE!” Ron Noble, the secret head of the International Crime Exchange, plots to frame Superman for accidental homicide in a boxing exhibition.

This story line is continued in [Action Comics #359](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_359), “THE CASE OF THE PEOPLE VS. SUPERMAN!” Superman apparently stands trial for the accidental killing of Ron Noble.

It isn't clear from the references what the result  of the case was but in [Action Comics #361](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_361), Superman meets up with the Parasite again (Action Comics #360 seems to be a Supergirl special.

Answer (score -3):

He absolutely kills Zod. Zod has no powers, and he's essentially a human being at that point like Lara described to Superman when he was talking to her about his relationship with Lois. Superman breaks his hand, tosses him to a wall of ice, and lets him fall to nothingness and we're supposed to believe Zod survived it? If Clark was all messed up from the fight he got into at the diner after he lost his powers, how does Zod do anything after what Superman does to him? And we don't see *how* Superman gets his powers back. You can infer that it's just the reverse of the process to take them away, but the fact is we don't know. Only Superman knows. And if only Superman knows, how will Zod and his crew (assuming they survived the falls) know the process on how to regain their powers?