# Is there a depiction of Superman where he is an African American?

Tags: dc, superman, parallel-universe, dc-animated-universe

Is there a comic book, animation, or any other media where Superman is depicted as being an African American?

I know that there are alternate universes where he is, for example, a Soviet, but I'm more interested if there's a depiction of a black Superman.

And I'm even more interested if in this universe he lives in the USA.

Comment: If Cavill leaves DCEU, Warner Bros. is planning to feature an African-American as Superman. I was going to ask the same question yesterday after the news broke out..

Comment: "Black" != "African American"

Comment: I prefer African-Kryptonian

Comment: Does [Steel (John Henry Irons)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_(John_Henry_Irons)) count?

Comment: @AzorAhai I'm aware of that. It's because I was interested in these two scenarios: 1 - Is there a depiction of a black Superman? 2 - Is there a depiction of a black Superman who happens to be an American citizen? If we think too hard about it, I couldn't call him African American because we know that Superman ancestrals are from Krypton, and not from Africa. I asked specifically for an African American Superman because having one of the most iconic American heroes as a black person has a different weight due to the country's historical racial context.

Comment: @FernandoRibeiro Then why not just say "black American"?

Comment: @AzorAhai English is not my first language, I wasn't sure if it's politically correct to say "black American" rather than "African American", that's why I wrote it that way

Comment: @FernandoRibeiro No problem. "Black American" or even "black and American" more accurately describes what you're after, especially since Superman *isn't* ethnically African. Calling every black person "African American" leaves out people of Carribean descent for example.

Comment: As a white American, I would never use the term "Black American". That sounds like a minefield. Even though your logic is fine, the language is heavily connotative in the US. If you don't like it, don't get mad at me. I'm just saying it sounds like a "look over both shoulders before you say it" kind of term (even though its purely and logically not, but the _connotations_ are bad).

Comment: @JamieClinton It must be a regional thing, because where I live in America that would be perfectly acceptable for a white person to say.

Comment: @zabeus Maybe, I live in a heavily progressive area. As a libertarian, I have been an outcast here my whole life. I may have ptsd from the cultural wars and am just shying away from anything that will get me dirty looks (which is everything).

Comment: @AzorAhai Aren't black people of Caribbean descent mostly people whose ancestors were brought to the Caribbean from Africa relatively recently? ("Recent" being relative to human history, i.e. in the last ~500 years.) Kryptonians aside, most black people are indeed of relatively recent African descent, as far as I know.

Comment: @reirab This isn't really the place to get into it, but yes. But when people say "African American," they don't include Jamaicans, for instance. So if one of these Supermen was Jamaican, they wouldn't be "African American," but could be considered black. The recent trend is to prefer "black" to "African American." I'm not sure why Jamie thinks it's so taboo.

Comment: Superman comics first appeared in 1938. In a very different time. A black Kryptonian, crash landed around 1920 in Kansas, found by a white childless farmer couple, a young adult in 1938, now _that_ would be a very interesting story.

Comment: @gnasher The Civil rights movement might have been a lot different if Malcolm X had superpowers and was invulnerable

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There are at least five. (and an unnamed one)

## Sunshine Superman

First appeared in *Animal Man* #23 (1990), as an illusion of sorts (generated by Psycho-Pirate's mask), along with other twisted versions of known characters. Then, his nationality is uncertain.

[image: Sunshine Superman]

## Kal-El of Earth D

Featured in *Legends of the DC Universe: Crisis on Infinite Earths* (1999).

This one is part of the "Justice Alliance of America". "America" being often used as a (perhaps ambiguous) shortcut for "USA" by writers, I would say there is a chance this Superman was an USA citizen too.

[image: Kal-El of Earth D]

## Kalel of Earth-23

Introduced in *Final Crisis* (2009).

Also known as Calvin Ellis, and plenty from the USA, which he is President of!

[image: Kalel Earth 23]

This is indeed a nod to Barack Obama, as revealed in [this Daily Record interview](https://www.dailyrecord.co.uk/entertainment/celebrity/exclusive-comics-writer-grant-morrison-1007392) of writer Grant Morrison:

> Grant created the characters for the last instalment of DC Comics
> series Final Crisis 7.
>
> **He was inspired by a joke Obama made in a speech - in which he denied
> he was from Superman's home planet Krypton** - and a report that Beyonce
> wants to play a superhero on screen.
>
> Grant told the Record: "I wanted to do something special for the last
> part of this huge comic book series.
>
> "**As I was writing it, I heard Obama making a joke about being born on
> the planet Krypton and being sent to Earth by his father Jor-El to
> save the world.
>
> "I thought it would be a fitting end to all the darkness in America
> recently.**
>
> "All the comics have been dealing with darkness recently and, having
> defeated evil, it's now time to celebrate."
>
> The comic, which comes out in the UK today, shows the president in the
> White House's Oval Office as he prepares to transform into his
> superhero alter-ego.
>
> Grant, who controversially killed off Batman last year for the comic
> series, added: "In this issue, we don't see him flying to Scotland -
> but who knows in future editions?
>
> "I hope to do more things with the Obama character next year."

## Val-Zod of Earth-2

Who was *adopted* by the house of El, and took the Superman mantra afterwards. First appeared in *Earth 2* #19 (2014).

As for his Earth time, he is first encountered beneath Arkham Base, after having spent a good chunk of his early life in his space capsule. I'm no law expert, but I think that qualifies as USA citizen (or at least resident). As Gaultheria rightly points in [a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194787/is-there-a-depiction-of-superman-where-he-is-an-african-american/194788?noredirect=1#comment534270_194788) though,

> I think that Val-Zod, a recent immigrant to Earth whom I believe never took on American citizenship or a secret identity as a human, technically doesn't meet either the "African" or "American" criteria.

He would then belong in the list as "a depiction of a Black Superman", as mentioned in the question's body.

[image: Val-Zod]

## Harvey Dent

Yes, you read that right. You learn something every day, I guess! In the [*Tangent Comics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_Comics) (1997), Harvey Dent was Black, and discovered he had powers. He reached out to help citizens, which in turn named him Superman. He lived in New York.

*(NB: Harvey Dent is usually the civilian identity of supervillain Two-Face)*

[image: Harvey Dent as Superman]

---

There's an unnamed Black Superman who appeared in *Superman/Batman* #25 (2006),  when Superman and Batman call upon their Multiverses counterparts for help. However, this is literally the only panel this guy appears in, he doesn't have a name, even less a nationality.

[image: Unnamed Black Superman]

Also worth noticing that some of the above made an appearance in the *Supermen of the Multiverse* panel below. Some extra Supermen are a bit too blurry to be sure they're black, but it's a possibility.

[image: Supermen of the Multiverse]

Comment: Kalel of Earth-23 is basically "What if Obama was Superman?" :)
Thanks for the answer, now I'll take a look into the story of each of them.

Comment: There's also the one that was killed by Superboy Prime at the Fortress of Solitude along with Lois, during his Multiverse rampage.

Comment: @Petersaber didn't know that one! I'll get digging right away, thanks for the hint! :)

Comment: The number of them is quite surprising, to be honest. I was expecting two or maybe three, but we are already on 5. I asked this question because of the backlash that occurred due to the rumor that Michael B. Jordan might play Superman after Henry Cavill was dismissed from the role in the DCEU.

Comment: I think that Val-Zod, a recent immigrant to Earth whom I believe never took on American citizenship or a secret identity as a human, technically doesn't meet either the "African" or "American" criteria.  I'd say that he still belongs on the list, but as an honourable mention.

Comment: Total nitpick: Wouldn't it just be "nowhere" ? The dude isn't even human. He's an (illegal ?) alien.

Comment: @Gaultheria I don't think you can say he's African-American in 3 of the others (and the multiverse panel) either. He's from Krypton, right? Not Africa. Only Harvey Dent seems to be potentially African-American.

Comment: @FernandoRibeiro - I guess they took [the JibJab video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVFdAJRVm94) seriously.

Comment: @JaccovanDorp Superman probably has no nationality, but Clark Kent (or whatever civil alias) has to. I guess Calvin Ellis, USA President, has to be a USA citizen, per the [natural-born citizen clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural-born-citizen_clause#Constitutional_provisions). See also [Is Clark Kent a legally adopted U.S. Citizen?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/125062/98028)

Comment: But if an african-american couple adopted an irish child, that child wouldn't count as african-american either. Sure, Clark Kent counts as american, but as far as i'm aware, there's no "official race membership" (but im european. If there is a race registration, then that's a racist thing that should be abolished.). Therefore, while he might officially count as american, I don't think that even with an african-american look, calling him one would be just as inaccurate as calling him [his-parents-racial-group].

Comment: "America" is *not* a "mistaken shortcut" for "USA". The USA is the only place or country that people call "America", lots of people call it that, and no one refers to the continents together as "America" (they're *the Americas*, or *North America* and *South America*). *America* does indeed mean *the USA*, and that's correct. Language is defined by usage not technicalities.

Comment: @only_pro And even if people did refer to the continents collectively as "America," it still wouldn't be "mistaken" to call the country that. It would just be ambiguous, which is hardly unusual for natural languages in general or for place names specifically. There are _loads_ of duplicate place names. That does not make any of them "mistaken."

Comment: @only_pro You are absolutely completely wrong. Where I went to school, there is ONE continent named America, consisting of North America, Middle America, and South America. With several vey large countries, like Canada, Brasil, and the USA, and a few quite large ones, like Mexico and Argentina, and then a few others.

Comment: @gnasher729 That's nice, but no one calls it that. The USA is America. The contintent is also technically America.