# Was there ever an Asian Batman?

Tags: dc, batman

Given the recent popularity of questions regarding various portrayals of Superman (as [Asian](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/194793) or [African American](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/194787)), I noticed that I don't remember ever hearing about an Asian Batman.

I know of the popular Bruce Wayne, an African-American one and even a Russian one, but has there ever been an Asian portrayal of the Bat? (Excluding the whole Chinese Justice League which is a more recent addition).

Comment: Are you looking for answers in DC as a whole or limiting to  a specific area like the comics?

Comment: @TheLeathalCarrot I'm looking for cannon DC, hopefully from the golden age but if none occured there anything DC works.

Comment: @user14111 it has been mentioned in cannon that the Wayne's were originally from Britain and were one of the first families that helped build Gotham

Comment: In the series Kingdom Come, there was a new rendition of The Batmen Of Many Nations, including Dragon of China and Samurai of Japan.

Comment: Asian Batman? Come on. It's [_Kamchatka_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_(game)#Territories), not Kambatcha 

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes! There are at least two (and a debatable other).

## Bat Ninja

*Robin Annual* #3, "The Narrow Path" (1994) features a Japanese Robin trained under a Bat Ninja (not to be mistaken with the 2018 animated [*Batman Ninja*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7451284/), who's from Gotham). Unfortunately, this ninja only appears (and dies) in this issue, so not much is known of him.

[image: Bat-Ninja]

Granted, his armor is more reminiscent of those of the samurai, but he's described as a ninja.

[image: the ninja whose sign is a bat]

## Batman of Shanghai

*Batman of Shanghai* (2012) would also qualify.

It was made by a Chinese animation studio, Wolf Smoke, and was included in the [DC Nation shorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Nation_Shorts). It also features Chinese Catwoman and Chinese Bane.

It's apparently [featured on the new DC universe website](https://www.dcuniverse.com/videos/dc-nation-shorts-batman-of-shanghai/136/season-1/), but I can't access it since I'm not in the US.

---

A bit more debatable, but Damian *may* qualify. He's born to Bruce Wayne and Talia al Ghul, daughter of Ra's al Ghul, who depending on the versions is either Egyptian, or from somewhere in Arabia.

There are a few comics which deal with Damian becoming Batman. Up to oneself to decide if that's "Asian" enough, though it's highly possible that Damian has an US citizenship and not an Asian one. ("officially" speaking)

Comment: Wikipedia lists a Pakistani Batman known as ["Black Bat"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batmen_of_All_Nations#Members), without a source. I'm browsing through cheesy old issues to find that one... (I've only known Cassandra Cain to be referred as "Black Bat")

Comment: Goddamn, that animation is *beautiful*.

Comment: On a side note, _Batman Ninja_'s animation is gorgeous too.

Comment: ...was that a Chinese bane ?

Comment: @casualcoder that was indeed also a Chinese Bane, because why not?

Answer (score 13):

There have been a few Japanese adaptations of Batman, but one has sort of crossed over into the "official" US continuity.

In the 60s during the "Bat-Mania" era, there was a Japanese manga starring Batman, by Jiro Kuwata.

[image: Batmans: The Jiro Kuwata Batmanga poster]

It was wildly unique, and featured new villains like Lord Death Man, Dr. Faceless and the Human Ball.

Grant Morrison and other writers have folded some of those villains into the DC Comics adventures, with only the most hand-wavey of explanations as to how and when they connect with the rest of the stories.

CBR also did [a look at all the other Japanese adaptations of Batman over the years](https://www.cbr.com/batman-japan-manga-anime-history/).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in fact there are multiple in canon Asian Batmen.

Firstly there is the one you've already mentioned, Wang Baixi of the justice League of China.

But there's another two in Canon Asian Batman, firstly there's Jiro Osamu, known as The Batman of Japan.

[image: Batman of Japan]

There was also Heino Okata who went by the code name "Most Excellent Super-Bat" whose costume if you look closely is actually made up of interlocking Superman & Batman logos.

[image: Most Excellent Super Bat]

Comment: That's a good find! Also, this Super-Bat is cheating on the writer's part. :p but hey, you could add it as an answer tothat Asian Superman question, as far as I'm concerned I'd say it qualifies!

Answer (score 4):

### Terry McGinnis

[image: Terry McGinnis as Batman]

Yes, there is an Asian Batman in the comics: [Terry McGinnis](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Terrence_McGinnis_(White_Knight)). Terry was first introduced in the animated series *[Batman Beyond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Beyond)*, where he inherited the mantle of Batman from an elderly Bruce Wayne.

In the [*Batman: White Knight*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_White_Knight) or the [Murphyverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphyverse) comics universe, writer and artist Sean Murphy gave him a different background. In an [interview with Screen Rant](https://screenrant.com/terry-mcginnis-half-asian-batman-beyond-the-white-knight/), he explained his decision to make Terry half-Asian in the fifth issue of the series, *[Batman: Beyond the White Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Beyond_the_White_Knight)* (emphasis mine):

> The trick with Terry for me was how to make him a little different. I didn't want to just mirror exactly what happened with the Batman Beyond cartoon series. I wanted to make it unique, but sort of familiar at the same time. One of the things I really wanted to do is make him half Asian. I didn't realize this, but a ton of people--including myself--always assumed Terry was half Japanese, and half Irish, or something. Only because there's so much kanji in Neo-Gotham, and he has long, black, straight hair... like, a lot of people mistake him as being half Asian. Even though both of his parents are like, extremely white. So for this one, **I decided to make his mom Asian, and his dad is obviously Irish, just to finally create a new kind of Terry.** Maybe it's just window dressing, and it doesn't really affect story that much, but I just thought it was an interesting way to break out my Terry from the other Terrys out there. And obviously to diversify the line, which is important.

Answer (score 0):

Also there's a relatively new Batman literally called [Batman Ninja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Ninja)

> **Batman Ninja** (ニンジャバットマン Ninja Battoman) is a 2018 Japanese animated superhero film directed by Junpei Mizusaki and produced by Warner Bros., which features the DC Comics character Batman. Takashi Okazaki, the creator of Afro Samurai, is the character designer for the film. The first poster was revealed on October 5, 2017, and the trailers were released later on December 1, 2017. The film was released in the United States in digital format on April 24, 2018; it was released in physical formats on May 8 and was released theatrically in Japan on June 15. In its American release, writers Leo Chu and Eric Garcia have admitted to rewriting the film from the original Japanese script written by Kazuki Nakashima, ultimately making two entirely different versions of the same film.

[image: Batman Ninja DCAU poster]

Comment: Thank you for editing my answer I'm unsure how to make the pictures show up on this website

Comment: Is this Batman Asian?

Comment: He's a Japanese Batman

Comment: The synopsis on Wikipedia suggests he's Caucasian, and **just happens to have been sent back in time**: "*While battling Gorilla Grodd at Arkham Asylum, Batman is caught in Grodd's Quake Engine time displacement machine and sent to Feudal Japan"* (as mentioned in the [answer above](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/194828/20774)_