# Why couldn’t Lois drive Clark back to the North Pole in Superman II?

Tags: dc, superman, superman-2

In *Superman II*, many people ask how Clark got back from the North Pole with Lois by car. He knew he needed to go back to try and get his powers from Jor-El, if at all possible, after he got his ass beat at the diner and realized Zod and his crew were on Earth.

So the big question I have is: why couldn’t Lois drive him back? Instead, he resorted to hitchhiking in a Members Only jacket?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70909/how-do-superman-and-lois-lane-leave-the-north-pole?rq=1

Comment: In reality neither hitchhiking nor driving would have worked. I don’t think you can drive a normal car to the North Pole. Perhaps in the right season and with plenty of extra gas cans in the car.

Comment: A straight shot from Fairbanks Alaska to the North Pole is 1700 miles and I doubt there are any services. Plus you probably have to avoid mountains and other terrain. Call it 2000 miles after driving around things. Without highways it could take days or weeks to cover that distance in a land vehicle. You’d have to have food, water, and fuel for the trip. There’s no chance of driving a regular car or hitchhiking there. According to WikiVoyage: *The North Pole can only be reached on expeditions specifically mounted for the purpose. Most travel primarily by air*

Comment: I understand you can’t get there by car, but they already drove back together, so it’s assumed they somehow got south by car, which supports that they can somehow get back by car,  but then he goes back north on foot … and I know you can’t drive to the North Pole… But his girlfriend just leaves him to fend for himself in the elements. Was she required to report back to the Daily Planet and she had to leave him stranded there? See what I’m saying?